# How to handle permissions/validation in django.auth.contrib

Tags: django, django-views

When implementing `django.auth.contrib` there are a number of views such as `password_reset_done` that  should only be visible after a specific action (each following on from a successful form submission).

However there does not appear to be any inbuilt validation/authentication of these specific use cases. What's the best practice for handling these views? Should we subclass the class view? Have I missed a built in function?

Comment: What's the harm in showing a user the password reset done page if they navigate directly to the URL themselves? I don't think it contains any sensitive info, so maybe it doesn't make sense but I don't think there's a security concern in terms of denying access to that page unless they just completed the reset form.

Comment: @azundo It's just about being internally consistent. If a reset wasn't successful the page shouldn't be accessible.